# How to keep only a piece of HTML code in Webbrowser VB.Net?

Tags: html, vb.net, iframe, webbrowser-control

I'm a web developer but now I have to make a windows-based program using VB.net. I have two website domain A and B that B is shown in A using an ifram element. The code is like this:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" src="//B.com/newsgroup.php?id=4"></iframe>
```

**B.com** stands for my second domain.
I want to use Webbrowser control in VB.net to show my website **A** to my consumers. Now for some reasons I want to show ONLY the ifram which contains B contents and the important thing is that first website's domain shouldn't change.

I tried to use `wb1.DocumentText = iFramCode` but instead of showing ifram, I only get a ifram which the URI of SRC was written! So I think the best method is that I remove all of the code and only keep the iFram's code like cutting head and end of a cucumber!

What I have to do to only keep a specified piece of HTML by deleting other codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Dim iFrame = wb1.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("iframe")

Dim iFrameContents = iFrame.InnerText
Dim wb2 as New WebBrowser
wb2.Navigate(String.Empty)
wb2.Document.Write(iFrameContents)
```

Comment: This answer would be better with some words of explanation or links to documentation. It might answer the question, but how would anyone know without copy/pasting this random code and running it? A good answer teaches *why* at the same time it shows *how*

Comment: Sorry but: InnerText' is not a member of System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection
.

Comment: Also it'll change the domain to null one. it's like that I start a ifram in a local html file!